# How do I make a function with a parameter called val of type string and return a number extracting/eliminating all non-numeric characters;

Tags: javascript

function extractNumber(val) {

// I need another way, to try to solve this function, this way I'm using it didn't work correctly //

return  val.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'')

}

Examples of what the result should look like:

'oo'        => NaN

'57o'       => 57

'n1.5'      => 1.5

'n1,5'      => 15

Comment: I don't need it to be a function and be in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the examples you provided, you could do something like this:

```js
function extractNumber(val) {
  return val.replace(/^(-)|[^0-9.]+/g, '$1') || 'NaN'
}

let strings = ['oo', '57o', 'n1.5', 'n1,5']

strings.forEach(s => {
  console.log(extractNumber(s))
})
```

Comment: Can you make some comments for me to understand what is happening in the code for me to study?

Comment: You can study the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/FFWXeO/1

Answer (score 0):

```
const extractNumber = (val) => val.replaceAll(/[^\d]/g, "");
```

example:

```
> extractNumber("ab23b1b512b12")
'23151212'
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.